# Initialize struct from Data in Swift 3

Tags: swift, struct, enums, initialization, memory-layout

I have a `Struct` named `MyContiguousStruct` whose memory layout has no padding.

```
struct MyContiguousStruct {
    let ivar1: UInt8
    let ivar2: UInt8
    let ivar3: UInt16
    let ivar4: UInt16
}
```

My initializer works (great) like this:

```
init?(data: Data) {
    guard data.count == MemoryLayout<Self>.size else { return nil }
    self = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
}
```

I decided to change `ivar1`'s type from a `UInt8` to an enum with a `rawValue` of `UInt8` like so:

```
struct MyContiguousStruct {
    let ivar1: EnumWithRawValueUInt8
    let ivar2: UInt8
    let ivar3: UInt16
    let ivar4: UInt16
}
```

but now am getting what appears to be an initialized  `MyContiguousStruct`, but `ivar1` isn't an initialized enum. I know I can read in the the data byte by byte, i.e:

```
ivar1 = data[0]
ivar2 = data[1]
// ...
```

but that means I can't throw this into a protocol I can attach to contiguously stored types. How can I ensure the enum is initialized?

Comment: Your coupling your makeshift serialization format to the layout format Swift uses. Dont do this, as struct layout algorithm can change at any time (such as to implement compaction)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to parse it manually. Enums can be represented by a raw value, but their underlaying Type is not that value (as they are in some languages). The added capabilities are a result of adhering to the [RawRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rawrepresentable/1538354-init) protocol, not by changing the Type or the storage of that Type.

If you don't want to manually parse the data, one decent work around would be to make `ivar1` private and have a computed property for your enum. 
E.g.

```
private let _ivar1: UInt8
var ivar1: EnumWithRawValueUInt8? {
    return EnumWithRawValueUInt8(rawValue: _ivar1)
}
```